# When pushing a React app to GitHub pages, is it required that the default remote branch be `gh-pages`?

Tags: reactjs, git, github

As a side project, I am developing a simple local React app, using Create React App.  I periodically push my edits online, to GitHub pages, using `npm run deploy`.  As expected, the GitHub repo for this project now has two branches:

```
master
gh-pages
```

In this GitHub repo, the default branch is `gh-pages`.

**Does `npm run deploy` require that the default branch be `gh-pages`?  Or can I safely change it to `master` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIwq2.jpg)), without it affecting `npm run deploy`?**  Specifically, I would like to change the default branch to `master`, and still be able to push my local app to GitHub pages.<sup>1</sup>

The reason I’d like to change the default branch to `master` is because the `master` branch is the branch that actually displays the code I wrote, as well as the README file for the GitHub repo.  So I'd like to share a link to this repo with collaborators/potential employers, and have my code/README file displayed by default.

- My app on GitHub pages is here:   https://cagross.github.io/react-specials/
- The GitHub repo is here:  https://github.com/cagross/react-specials

Thanks.

---

<sup>1</sup> Whether I continue to do that with `npm run deploy` or some other command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else would like an answer to this question, my GitHub issue finally had a reply, and with some possible answers ([see here](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages/issues/32)).  I unfortunately haven't been able to test the suggestions in that post, as I have since moved my app away from GitHub pages.  But the answers in that post seem viable enough to try.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites

> The default publishing source **for user and organization sites** is the `master` branch. If the repository for your user or organization site has a `master` branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch. **You cannot choose a different publishing source for user or organization sites**.
>
> The default publishing source **for a project site** is the `gh-pages` branch. If the repository for your project site has a `gh-pages` branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch.
>
> Project sites can also be published from the `master` branch or a `/docs` folder on the `master` branch.

(Emphasize is mine — *phd*)

Comment: OK. So if I change the default branch in the GitHub repo to `master` (as in this screenshot, https://imgur.com/a/MoV1v5l), will I still be able to push app edits to GitHub pages with `npm run deploy`?  The link you posted seems to say that the source files for the GitHub pages app are in the gh-pages branch, which I understand.  But I don't think that doesn't answer my question.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You shouldn't change the default branch, you should change the branch for GitHub Pages. The first tab of the Settings, section "GitHub Pages".

Comment: Currently that setting is set to `gh-pages` (screenshot:  https://i.imgur.com/LhJv2fV.jpg).  That seems to be the setting I want, since my app is functioning as expected on GH pages.  Are you saying I should change this to `master`?  If so, won't that break the app on GitHub Pages?  To clarify, here is my issue.  When visitors view my repo (https://github.com/cagross/react-specials), the `gh-pages` branch is displayed by default.  I'd like to ensure the `master` branch is displayed by default.  Can I do that, without breaking my app (or how I push changes to my app)?

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Your initial question was "*is it required that the default remote branch be `gh-pages`?*" The docs answers: `master` is required for user and organization sites, `gh-pages` is the default for a project site (this is your case), but for a project site the branch could be changed to `master` or directory `/docs` at `master`. It's not required. You're now using the default configuration (`gh-pages` for a project site) and it seems ok for me.

Comment: OK.  Maybe I need to re-phrase my question.  The question was specifically with the command `npm run deploy`.  To clarify, currently I execute `npm run deploy` to push my local edits to GitHub pages.  If I change the default repo from `gh-pages` to `master`, then execute `npm run deploy` again, will it continue to push my local edits to GH pages without issue?  I don't think the docs page you linked answers that.

Comment: Let me know if this re-phrasing is clearer, and I'll then edit my original question.

Comment: I guess the question might be:  To what GitHub branch does `npm run deploy` push edits?  Does it push edits to the `gh-pages` branch?  Or does it push edits to whatever branch I have set for my default branch?

Comment: No idea. I'm a Python programmer, not JS. The destination branch is probably configured in React app development config whatever it is (like `package.json`).

Comment: OK no problem.  I'll keep nosing around and see what I can find.